# execute curl command in python

Tags: python, curl, esb

I have already gone through few StackOverflow existing links for this query, did not help me.

I would like to run few curl command(4) and each curl commands give output. From that output, I would like to parse the few group ids for next command.

```
curl --basic -u admin:admin -d \'{ "name" : "test-dev" }\' --header \'Content-Type: application/json\' http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/serverGroups
```

I have tried with as ,

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import subprocess
bash_com = 'curl --basic -u admin:admin -d '{ "name" : "test-dev" }' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/serverGroups'
subprocess.Popen(bash_com)
output = subprocess.check_output(['bash','-c', bash_com]) # subprocess has check_output method
```

It gives me the syntax error, though I have changed from a single quote to double quote for that curl command.

I have been trying with Pycurl but i have to look more into that. Is there any way we can run curl commands in python and can parse the output values and pass it to next curl command.

Comment: What is the syntax error?

Comment: It gives syntax error to admin:admin

Comment: # python -x api.py
  File "api.py", line 4
    bash_com = curl --basic -u admin:admin -d '{ "name" : "test-dev" }' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/serverGroups
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Use triple quotes: `bash_com = """curl --basic -u admin:admin -d '{ "name" : "test-dev" }' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/serverGroups"""`.

Comment: String formatting is incorrect. `"""curl --basic -u admin:admin -d '{ "name" : "test-dev" }' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/serverGroups"""` should work

Comment: I have added the triple quote , can see diff error like raise child_excpetion. so subprocess.Popen(bash_com) is not wokring as expected.

Comment: # python api.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "api.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(bash_com)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 642, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/subprocess.py", line 1234, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory

Comment: Make sure the `cUrl` command works by itself.

Comment: as I know `Popen` expects list `['curl', '--basic', ...]`

Comment: If I run the curl command over the command line it works perfectly
# curl --basic -u admin:admin -d '{ "name" : "test-dev" }' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/serverGroups
{"href":"http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/serverGroups/0c4f0746-da43-4925-aaea-53cd683844b5","serverCount":0,"name":"test-dev","id":"0c4f0746-da43-4925-aaea-53cd683844b5"}

Comment: you can use `shlex.split(bash_com)` to split command - `Popen(shlex.split(bash_com))` - because normal `split()` may split in wrong way.

Comment: if i use split method to convert into the list - will that execute that command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use os.popen with

```
fh = os.popen(bash_com, 'r')
data = fh.read()
fh.close()
```

Or you can use subprocess like this

```
cmds = ['ls', '-l', ]

try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmds, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
    retcode = 0
except subprocess.CalledProcessError, e:
    retcode = e.returncode
    output = e.output

print output
```

There you have to organize your command and params in a list.

Or you just go the easy way and use requests.get(...).

**And do not forget:** Using popen you can get shell injections via parameters of your command!

Answer (score 0):

Better output using os.open(bash_com,'r') and then fh.read()

## python api.py

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
199   172    0   172    0    27   3948    619 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  4027
**{"href":"http://localhost:8080/mmc/api/serverGroups/39a28908-3fae-4903-adb5-06a3b7bb06d8","serverCount":0,"name":"test-dev","id":"39a28908-3fae-4903-adb5-06a3b7bb06d8"}**

trying understand that fh.read() has executed the curl command? please correct me

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to redirect the curl commands output to text file and then parse the file via JSON. All I am trying to get "id" from about output.

```
fh = os.popen(bash_com,'r')
data = fh.read()

newf = open("/var/tmp/t1.txt",'w')
sys.stdout = newf
print data

with open("/var/tmp/t1.txt") as json_data:
    j = json.load(json_data)
    print j['id']
```

I have checked the files content in JSONlint.com and got VALID JSON on it. It is throwing "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded" at json.load line. Is there anything need to perform before parsing the redirected file.